# Comparing internal energy of materials at boiling point or melting point

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, states-of-matter

I am in grade 11th and have studied about internal energy that it is function of only temperature and none other quantity. My question is that when a solid melts, or a liquid vaporizes, it does at a fixed and particular temperature. Does the internal energy of the body change at this time.

If internal energy does not change then where does the applied energy go (Law of conservation of energy violates).

If internal energy does increase, then it depends on something else too (other than temp since temp is constant while melting or boiling). What thing could it be?

So what exactly happens to the internal energy when a substance changes its state..?

Comment: Have you asked your teacher this question?

Comment: @BobD I'll ask it once the school reopens...

Answer (score 1):

Internal energy is only a function of temperature in the case of an ideal gas.

When a solid or liquid changes phase at constant temperature and pressure the heat added or extracted increases or decreases the potential energy component of internal energy as molecules move farther apart or closer together.

Hope this helps

Comment: That does explain something. So it means that the fact "Internal energy is a function of temperature only" is valid only for ideal gases and not truly applicable for solids and liquids. Then what else does internal energy depend on in cases of solids and liquids??

Comment: Everything that doesn’t exist in the ideal gas or is ignored: strain energy, chemical energy, interfaces, defects such as vacancies and dislocations, surface energy (sometimes classified as a defect), electrical polarization, magnetization, and so on.

Comment: @UtkarshSahu You may have misunderstood me.  Similar to an ideal gas, the change in internal energy of a liquid and solid is dependent on temperature only,  provided the liquid or solid does not undergo a phase change. The internal energy of an ideal gas, on the other hand, is only dependent  on temperature under all conditions where ideal gas behavior is observed.

Comment: Ohh... Now I got the point...

Answer (score 1):

With a change in phase, the internal energy changes, but the temperature does not change. For example, if you add heat to a liquid (e.g., water) and it changes state to a vapor (e.g, steam)  the internal energy of the system  increases due to the heat added according to the first law of thermodynamics: $Q = \Delta U$ in this case, where $Q$ is heat added and $\Delta U$ is change in internal energy.

The conditions for a single phase do not apply for a change in phase.  For example, the internal energy for an ideal gas is a function of temperature is only true for no change in phase (no cooling of the gas to a liquid phase).